# please let me know how to validate a ssn field in triggers that it should only contain numbers

Tags: before-trigger

```
trigger t1can on candidate__c (before insert) {
    for (candidate__c can: Trigger.new){
        if(can.email__c == Null)
            can.addError('Email field is required');
    } 
    for (candidate__c can: Trigger.new){
        if(isnumber(can.ssn__c),'Ssn should be in number', 'null')
    }
}
```

Comment: A validation rule and a trigger are separate things. This looks out of place here: `if(isnumber(can.ssn__c),'Ssn should be in number', 'null')`

Comment: [Useful Validation Rules](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_useful_validation_formulas.pdf)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because duplicate user account spamming questions and comments http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162531/before-insert-trigger-fires-with-a-validation-rule-that-ssn-number-should-not-be

Comment: @Eric I've merged the two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. You no need to have a separate loop for each and every check. Instead do them in a single loop. To check for numbers, use [isNumeric()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) in String class.

```
trigger t1can on candidate__c (before insert) {
    for (candidate__c can: Trigger.new){
        if(can.email__c == Null)
            can.addError('Email field is required');

        // check for null first, then use isNumeric() static method to check for numeric
        if(String.isNotEmpty(can.ssn__c) && !can.ssn__c.isNumeric()){
            can.addError('SSN should be in number');
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: What if there are some spaces in the entered number such as 123 456 123? You should replace all the spaces before checking for "IsNumeric".

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of banging on screws with a hammer, here.

> ## [Visual Development – When to Click Instead of Write Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/12/forcedotcom-declarative-development.html)
>
> [image: Reinventing the wheel]
>
> ...
>
> ## Examples for Declarative Development versus Code
>
> Here are some use cases and examples for functionality that can easily be build declaratively, without writing a single line of code:
>
> ...
>
> - Enforce Business Rules with **Validation Rules** whenever possible instead of **Triggers** and **code**
>   Don’t want to allow users to save the order if a piece of information is missing? Validation Rules is a fast and easy-to-use alternative to writing custom Visualforce pages and controllers or Apex Triggers.

Both of the validations you have are easy to implement declaratively.

**Email Validation**

```
ISNULL(Email)
```

**SSN Validation**

```
NOT(ISNUMBER(SSN__c))
```

Or, if you want to allow spaces/dashes:

```
NOT(REGEX(Counsyl_ID__c, "[1-9 -]*"))
```

You can even get into validating specific formats if you're into that. The point is, you can do everything required here without a single line of `Apex`. That's a win.